# Can I edit some rules in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

I wish to change the rule 'Left curly braces should be located at the end of lines of code' since we are using a different convention.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Googling "sonarqube edit rules" returns many results that look like they explain what you are trying to do - please take a look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Sonarqube intends to provide the least possible configuration possible on rules: you should deactivate the rule with key `squid:LeftCurlyBraceEndLineCheck` and I am guessing that you want to activate the rule : `squid:LeftCurlyBraceStartLineCheck`

Please note that those rules have nothing to do with Checkstyle.

Comment: Ohh. I didn't know that rule exists. Thanks!